# datagridview with stimulsoft

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, stimulsoft

Code is write in C# in windows forms
I have button Print,which onclick must open Stimulsoft and sent dataGridView1 to Stimulsoft. How can I do it?Please help,I can not find answer on web

```
    private void Table_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetTable();


    }
    private DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable dtRadnice = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_csDataFin))
        {

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("traziuEvidenciji", conn);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DateTime dtPocetak;
            DateTime dtZavrsetak;
            dtPocetak = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
            dtZavrsetak = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;

            comm.Parameters.Add("@dtPocetak", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtPocetak;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@dtZavrsetak", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtZavrsetak;

            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            dtRadnice.Load(reader);


        }
        return dtRadnice;
    }
   private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //some text
     }
```

This is stored procedure which put data into dataGridView

```
ALTER PROCEDURE traziuEvidenciji

@dtPocetak datetime,
@dtZavrsetak datetime
 AS
 BEGIN
 SELECT EvidencijaORadu.IDEvidencijaORadu
   ,Korisnik_s.Name
  ,EvidencijaORadu.DateOfMonth
  ,EvidencijaORadu.PocetakRada
  ,EvidencijaORadu.ZavrsetakRada
  ,EvidencijaORadu.RedovnoRadnoVrijeme


FROM EvidencijaORadu
  inner join [EmmettShared].dbo.[Korisnik_s] on Korisnik_s.IDKorisnik= 
  EvidencijaORadu.KorisnikID
  WHERE [DateOfMonth] BETWEEN CAST( @dtPocetak AS date) AND 
 CAST(@dtZavrsetak AS DATE)
    ORDER BY DateOfMonth ASC

    END
```

Comment: Try to express the minimal required details about the problem you are trying to solve. Which stimulsoft product are you trying to use and for what result? Is your problem about general stimulsoft integration or related to that specific given sql querying method? It seems the latter is irrelevant.

Comment: My problem is : on what way data form dataGridView1 I can send to stimulsoft report?When I open stimulsoft Report.mrt I want see same table which is in datagridview in my windiwsform Table

Comment: can you confirm which type of data you wish to pass to stimulsoft.

Comment: @VickyS  varchar and datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out stimulsoft documentation? For example:

- Sample code: https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/samples/winforms/user-data-in-reports
- API reference: https://admin.stimulsoft.com/documentation/classreference-net/

It seems you have many options to push data to Stimulsoft reports. In particular you could be interested in using the method `StiReport.RegData(DataTable data)`. At least [it exists based on API reference](https://admin.stimulsoft.com/documentation/classreference-net/Stimulsoft_Report_StiReport_RegData@DataTable.html).

Also, there seems to be a bunch of videos by them in youtube. For example, check out this one [Binding DataSet at Runtime - Stimulsoft Reports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lfDqjYm82E).